# Cannot modify site.tags from Jekyll plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm developing a plugin to facilitate multilingual Jekyll sites, and as part of this I have to categorise posts according to their language.

I'm trying to tag the post according to its language, so I have overwritten the `aggregate_post_info` method, but when I print the `site.tags` variable, **it is empty**.

```
module Jekyll
    class Site

        alias_method :_aggregate_post_info, :aggregate_post_info
        def aggregate_post_info(post)
            _aggregate_post_info(post)
            @tags[post.data['lang']] << post
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved something similar by defining my own language specific variables, like in this simplified example:

```
for post in site.posts.docs do
    lang = post.data['lang']
    for tag in post.data['tags'] do
        slug = jekyll_tagging_slug(tag)
        site.config['t'][lang]['tagnames'] = slug
    end
end
```

I also automatically generate tag pages (and category pages using a different approach without plug-ins), avoid name collisions for multiple languages, and precompute aggregate counts for better performance.  The whole thing is described in two blog posts http://www.guido-flohr.net/multilang-with-jekyll/ and http://www.guido-flohr.net/jekyll-multilang-tags/.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the post language as a tag, i.e. `tags: [english, ruby, etc]`, avoiding altogether the monkey patching. So, when you want to show only `lang`-tagged posts, you simply filter them:

```
<ul class="posts">
{% for post in site.tags.english %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This way, most of the work is done by Jekyll, saving you some time and effort. :)

Comment: Well really this is the exact opposite of saving me time and effort. I'd love for my plugin to automatically tag the posts, rather I doing it myself.